# find command to prune only files starting with dot(filter files that start with dot)

Tags: linux, find

The following find command filters the files and directories starting with dot symbol.

```
find $PWD \( -name '.*' -prune \) -o -print
```

Where as adding the "-type f" condition does not filter files starting with dot.

```
find $PWD \( -name '.*' -type f -prune \) -o -print # this does not work
```

How to prune only files starting with dot

**EDIT 1:** Clarification on "Does not work"

The command lists the file starting with the dot operator. Later found that it was a symbolic link to another file(which does not start with dot). Tried using -L (follow symbolic links) option like below which still listed the symbolic link file starting with dot.

```
find -L $PWD \( -name '.*' -type f -prune \) -o -print
```

Comment: Explain `does not work`? There is no particular reason to `-prune` them rather than just `-not name '.*'` if you want to only prune dot files, but your logic should still omit dot files (just not hidden directories).

Comment: Based on that edit, seems like an XY problem. Might be worth deleting this question and posting a new one (probably better placed on the [unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)) about why find options are still aplied to symlink names with `-L` on. Something like `find "$PWD" ! \( -type l -lname '.*' -o -type f -name '.*' \)` would probably be close to working, but it will omit symlinks that point to files AND directories starting with a dot, so probably not quite what's wanted here.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a bit confused about the meaning of "prune": `-prune` means *do not descend into subdirectory*, so it does not really make sense with `-type f`.

Comment: `Does not make sense` and `does not work` are two different things. His command should still omit dot files, just not because of the `-prune`.

Comment: It works, it's just that the meaning is not clear. His command, due to parentheses, says: "print files starting with a dot or print anything else", which basically means it will print everything. But the OP's question "How to prune only files starting with dot" does not sound clear either. Assuming he wants to *print* only files starting with a dot, he can simply do: `find $PWD -name '.*' -type f`.

Comment: Not quite. There is no explicit action on the left side of the `-o`, so it won't take any action if the files start with a dot. If they do not it will print them. So logically this is something like `find files that start with a dot OR print files (that do not)`, which contains extraneous logic, but should still do what he wants (at least the way I'm reading the question).

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait until the OP clarifies the question :).

Comment: @SukkoPera edited the answer for more clarification.

Comment: @BroSlow His command, due to parentheses, says: "print files starting with a dot or print anything else". Thats not what i wanted the command to say. My understanding is the left side of -o says "files starting with dot is pruned(prune is an action) and the right side says "print everything". Why do you think the left side of "-o" asks to print. Since -prune action is explictly mentioned and hence find command should not take the default -print action.

Comment: Actually it all looks more confused to me. You hadn't mentioned links at all in the original question! I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit Kindof, but the reason the left side isn't printed is because there's an explicit `-print` on the right side of the `-o`, not because of the `-prune`. The `-prune` itself has no effect when dealing with regular files, it works like a true no-op here, and is completely extraneous.